# Redirect only images to static domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How it's possible to 301 redirect all image (png, jpg, gif) requests from www.example.com to static.example.com?

My htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it for you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)\.(gif|png|jpg)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://static.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Let me know how it works for you.